# Swing flow layout break element in scrollable JPanel

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, awt, layout-manager

I'm trying to put multiple `JPanel` cards into my main panel. and if new card panel does not fit I want it to be placed in next line. In the image below, you see that all my card panels go to right and if I set `HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS` horizontal scroll works. So here I want 4 card panel in each line of my main panel so that vertical scroll works.

```
public class PanelTraining extends JPanel{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


    public PanelTraining(List<FccMeta> ffcms) {
        super(new BorderLayout()); // set layout to absolute
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(880, 580));
        setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.decode("#A11E1E"),1, true));

        JPanel pnlChart = new JPanel();

        pnlChart.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(860, 180));
        pnlChart.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
        add(pnlChart, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        JPanel pnlTrSet = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEADING, 5, 5));
        //pnlTrSet.setSize(860, 380);

        for (FccMeta fccMeta : ffcms) {
            JPanel pnlCard = new MyCustomPanelCard();
            pnlTrSet.add(pnlCard);
        }


        JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(pnlTrSet);
        //scroll.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(860, 380));
        scroll.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        scroll.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        add(scroll, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    }
}
```

[image]

**EDIT** according to the answer given below. I changed my implementation by [this Class](http://www.camick.com/java/source/ScrollablePanel.java)

```
ScrollablePanel pnlTrSet = new ScrollablePanel(new FlowLayout());
pnlTrSet.setScrollableWidth( ScrollablePanel.ScrollableSizeHint.FIT );
pnlTrSet.setScrollableBlockIncrement(
       ScrollablePanel.VERTICAL, ScrollablePanel.IncrementType.PIXELS, 230);
```

[image]

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) Provide ASCII art or a simple drawing of the *intended* layout of the GUI at minimum size, and if resizable, with more width and height.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to implement the `Scrollable` interface of your panel to have the width fixed to the size of the viewport of the scrollpane.

Basically you need to override the `getScrollableTracksViewportWidth()` method to return “true”.

An easy way to do this is to use the [Scrollable Panel](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/12/20/scrollable-panel/). It has a method that allows you to control this property.

Edit:

The above will only prevent the horizontal scrollbar from appearing. However the FlowLayout will continue to display all the buttons on a single row because the preferred size calculation of the panel is still not correct.

To get the buttons to wrap, you must replace the FlowLayout of your panel with the [Wrap Layout](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/06/wrap-layout/).  The `Wrap Layout` will recalculate the preferred height of the panel correctly so that the components can wrap and the vertical scrollbar can appear.

Comment: Could you please detail your answer? what do you mean by the Scrollable interface of my panel

Comment: @gabby, 1) Read the API for more information about the Scrollable interface. That is the first place to start when somebody suggests a class/interface you don't know about. 2) Search the forum/web for examples that use the method suggested. 3) Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Implementing a Scrolling-Savvy Client](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html#scrollable).

Comment: Yes I did. I updated my question by the result I got what you offered.

Comment: @gabby, was just updating my answer. The scrollbars still don't work because the preferred size of the panel is not calculated correctly.